# How to place an animation into a 3d landscape without everything breaking

Tags: linked-data

Consider a project that consists of separate .blend files:

1. 3d Terrain (created procedurally)
   [image]
2. Character animations
   [image]

The intention is to link both of those into a new file and place the character animation among the 3d landscape.

The alternative methods of creating 2d backgrounds works very well - until its time to have a moving camera shot.
When both files are linked together the problem begins:

To move the character to the intended location breaks some of its animation that involve boids (the 'fly' in this case).

To move the landscape to the character breaks the shape of the landscape because it is still procedural.

To apply the modifiers in the landscape (to make it non-procedural) kills my computer.

I'm guessing I may be unaware of a specific workflow or... linking method that avoids this issue?

Thankyou for any suggestions!

Comment: Hi John, just from my own painful experience: never ask question with "what is the best way" because your question will be closed as "opinioned based". I don't want to discuss whether this is senseful or not - i just want to tell you - it is like this. So you should edit your question and change into something like "how can i...."

Comment: Thankyou kindly for the tip Chris. I have edited the question title. This rule does indeed make perfect sense because the last thing anyone needs when creating art is an... opinion... ew!!!

Comment: I figured it out... it involves using a instanced collection of the boids system. That's my opinion ;)